# Power Query - multiple data types in one column (dates & text) - adding conditional column to break up data

Tags: powerquery

I have multiple data types in one column (dates & text) see table below -  I'm wanting to add new column so that one column has date values only and the new column has the text values only.
I guess that I need to add a conditional column but I don't know the language to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
Basically you duplicate the column, change the column type to one of the types (I changed to date type), therefore the text changed to errors.
I then changed errors to null values.
Then I added a conditional column and substituted the null values for the values in the original column.
See link below for example:

https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/11/30/extract-data-from-a-mixed-column/